# onScroll event not firing else{} function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to run a simple "onScroll do something" function.

When the visitor scrolls more than 20px away from the top window position the header is supposed to shrink down in size (along with it's content).
When the visitor scrolls back to the top (or <20px) the header is supposed to go back to it's original size (auto).

For some reason nothing I do seems to be working. The header (and the content) shrinks down fine, but the else{ } portion of the function does not fire. The header size does not change. It's like the size in the if{ } portion overrides everything else.

I just want to make a simple fixed header bar that shrinks (minimizes) once you scroll down the page and flips back to it's original size if you go back to the top.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a bunch!

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="http://froggyadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-93/full/placeholder%20-%20Copy%20(3).gif" />
</header>
<section>
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topW = $(window).stop().scrollTop();
    if (topW > 20) {
        $('header').animate({"height": "15%"}),
        $('header img').css({"height": "10%","width": "10%"});
    } else {
        $('header').animate("height", auto);
    }
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle** — http://jsfiddle.net/jwarddesign/NphFw/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/jwarddesign/NphFw/3/)

Comment: It's easier to help if you post your code.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle link and put the code in the body of the question.

Comment: Add jQuery as a dependency to your JSFiddle, also, your `.animate("height", auto)`, change to `.animate({ "height": "auto" })`, seems to work, although you're not able to scroll afterwards since there's not enough height for scrolling anymore.

Comment: It doesn't affect the size of header for the condition else{ }. It shrinks fine once you've scrolled - but it does not go back.

Comment: Check this code, is this it? http://jsfiddle.net/NphFw/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jwarddesign/NphFw/10/

Comment: Restore also the size of the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jwarddesign/NphFw/14/

Comment: Still not working correctly. Arrrrggg!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible to animate to "auto" height.

You could save the height before you're running the function, then you can animate it back to that height.

```
// Get the height
var h = $('header').outerHeight();

// Animate to the stored height
$('header').animate({"height": h})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NphFw/22/